# Regular function in a function is modifying the outer this context

Tags: javascript, scope, this

Please look at the code below.
I think the arrow functions do not have their own this. so they take context from wherever they are called but regular functions should have their own this (that is the one big difference between arrow and regular functions)

```
function test() {
  this.name = "outermost name value";
  const test1 = () => {
    const test2 = () => {
      this.name = "test2"; // expected to modify outermost name
    };
    test2();
    console.log(`Inside test 1 --> ${this.name}`); // expected to print test2 (Correct)
  };
  function test3() {
    this.name = "test3"; // expected to modify outermost name
    console.log(`Inside test3 --> ${this.name}`); // expected to print test3 (Correct)
    function test4() {
      this.name = "test4"; // should not modify outermost name as inner function should have own this
    }
    test4();
    console.log(`Inside test3 --> ${this.name}`); // expected to print test3 (Incorrect)
  }

  test1(); // test2
  console.log("After test 1, outermost name is --> ", this.name); // test2 (Correct)
  test3(); // test3
  console.log("After test 3, outermost name is --> ", this.name); // expected to print test3 (Incorrect)
  return;
}
test();
```

Here is what the output looks like

> Inside test 1 --> test2

> After test 1, outermost name is -->  test2

> Inside test3 --> test3

> Inside test3 --> test4

> After test 3, outermost name is -->  test4

I have mentioned the expectation in comments.
Am I doing something wrong or is the expectation wrong?

Comment: When you execute the test3, test4 is being executed same at test1, so if you are using always "this" is a reference object it will be change every time without "scope".

Comment: `this.name = "test3"; // expected to modify outermost name` - this won't modify the "outermost" `name`, for the same reason why `test4()` won't modify it. Also you said _"arrow functions do not have their own this. so they take context from wherever they are called"_, they don't get the context from where they are _called_, they get the context from where they are defined. So `this` in an arrow function essentially is the `this` from the surrounding scope they're defined in, while `this` in a regular function is its own value (which is the shared global object [eg: `window`]) when no context).

Comment: "*so they take context from wherever they are called*" - nope

Comment: Really you should [`"use strict"` mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode), to avoid using `this` to refer to globals

Comment: @NickParsons Actually both those statements are modifying it.
I added one more conosole.log before declaring test 4.
Here is what the output looks like

Inside test 1 --> test2
After test 1, outermost name is -->  test2
Inside test3 --> test3
Inside test3 --> test4
After test 3, outermost name is -->  test4

Comment: @SahilGoyal Yeah sorry, so when you call `test()` without a context as you are in your example, the `this` defaults to the global obj (if you're running this in a browser and not in strict mode, it will be `window`). So `this.name = "outermost name value"` in `test` becomes `window.name = "outermost name value"`. The same thing occurs when you call `test3()` and `test4()`, in both of these calls, no context is being provided so they're both updating `window`. In fact, all your functions are updating `window` object. If a context was provided to `test`/`3`/`4` the output would be different.

Comment: Omg, thank you so much , it makes sense now. I just called them with a different context and I am getting a different output which explains why I was getting the above output. 
Cheers!